# Basic: where to insert a ggplot into an rshiny dashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

I have two plots that I would like to display one below the other in my Shiny dashboard. I'm new enough that I don't know how to insert the two chart snippets into the main dashboard code.

```html
library(shiny)
library(semantic.dashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")

library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")
fig

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(color = "blue",title = "HMH Convalescent Plasma Transfusion Therapy", inverted = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(
    size = "thin", color = "teal",
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(tabName = "main", "Recipient Data", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem(tabName = "extra", "Donor Data", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      selected = 1,
      tabItem(
        tabName = "main",
        fluidRow(
          box(width = 8,
              title = "Graph 1",
              color = "green", ribbon = TRUE, title_side = "top right",
              column(width = 8,
                     plotOutput("boxplot1")
              )
          ),
          box(width = 8,
              title = "Graph 2",
              color = "red", ribbon = TRUE, title_side = "top right",
              column(width = 8,
                     plotlyOutput("dotplot1")
              )
          )
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "extra",
        fluidRow(
          dataTableOutput("carstable")
        )
      )
    )
  ), theme = "cerulean"
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  data("mtcars")
  colscale <- c(semantic_palette[["red"]], semantic_palette[["green"]], semantic_palette[["blue"]])
  mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am,levels=c(0,1),
                      labels=c("Automatic","Manual"))
  output$boxplot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = am, y = mpg)) +
      geom_boxplot(fill = semantic_palette[["green"]]) + 
      xlab("gearbox") + ylab("Miles per gallon")
  })
  
  output$dotplot1 <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
             + geom_point(aes(colour=factor(cyl), size = qsec))
             + scale_colour_manual(values = colscale)
    )
  })
  output$carstable <- renderDataTable(mtcars)
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Chart that needs inserting:

```html
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {  
  output$Plot <- renderPlot({  
    Figure %>% drop_na(Requirement) %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=Day,y=Patient,group=Patient,col=Requirement),lwd=2.5) + scale_color_manual(values=cols) + scale_y_continuous(trans="reverse",breaks=seq(1,50,1))+scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-14,24,1))+theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank()) + geom_vline(xintercept=0) + geom_point(data=Figure_Event, aes(x=Day,y=Patient,shape=Event),size=4) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,22)) + scale_color_discrete(breaks=c("AmbientAir","LowFlow","HighFlow", "NIPPV","MechanicalVentilation","ECMO"))
  })
})
```

2nd chart:

```html
ggplot(data=o2outcomes, aes(x=transfusion_date, y=ID, group=1)) +
  geom_line()+
  ylim(0, 100)+labs(y= "Number of Patients Transfused", x = "Transfusion Date")+ggtitle("Number of Patients Transfused Over Time") 
##create line graph
```

I know how basic this is. Just can't seem to get it going. Thanks. Also if someone knows how to make my title show up, that would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The source data for neither of your new plots, `Figure` and `o2outcomes` appear in your code, so we can't provide a complete answer for you.

That said, including the plots should be staightforward.  Just follow the pattern demonstrated by the two plotly outputs.  First, you add a `plotOutput("<yourId>")` to your `ui` function.  You can add them either to one of the existing boxes, or in (a) new box(es) of your own.  Then add `output$<yourId> <- renderPlot({...})` to your `server` function.  Your sample code for the first plot is already wrapped in a `renderPlot` (and `server` function): don't duplicate the wrapper.  The code for your second plot doesn't have the wrapper so you need to add it.

What title is missing?

Your code is not simple and self-contained.  If you can make it so, you increase your chance of getting useful answer greatly.